# how to derive the distribution of variable x conditional on x+y

Tags: binomial-distribution, multinomial-distribution, expectation-maximization

The question is from a typical example for E-M algorithm.

Let's say $(y_1,y_2,y_3)$ $\sim$ $\text{multinomial}(n;p_1,p_2,p_3)$, where $p_1+p_2+p_3=1$.

How can we derive the conditional distribution of $y_2$ given $y_2+y_3=n$?

The answer is $y_2|y_2+y_3 \sim \text{binomial}(n, p_2/(p_2+p_3)$).

Any idea on how to derive this rigorously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a more general result; yours is the special case $m=0$:

If $Y_1,Y_2,Y_3$ $\sim$ $\text{multinomial}(n;p_1,p_2,p_3)$ then the conditional 
distribution  of $Y_2$ given
$Y_1=m$ $(m\leq n)$
is $\text{binomial}( n-m, p_2/(p_2+p_3) )$:

\begin{eqnarray}
p( Y_2=y_2| Y_1=m) &=& p(Y_2=y_2, Y_1=m)/ P(Y_1=m)\\
&=&\frac{\binom{n}{m}\binom{n-m}{y_2} p_2^{y_2} p_3^{n-m-y_2}p_1^m } {\binom{n}{m} p_1^m (p_2+p_3)^{n-m}}\\
&=&\binom{n-m}{y_2} p_2^{y_2} p_3^{n-m-y_2} /(p_2 + p_3)^{n - m}
\end{eqnarray}